# python script to send a variable to wix source path

Tags: python, python-2.7, wix, wix3.7

I have a GUI generated using `wxpython` which is used to select the path required by `wix` project to create msi. The selected path from the GUI is written to the registry when clicked on *apply* button in the GUI.The selected path is stored in a variable say *data* i.e:

```
data='C :\Sandbox\build\Windows\release\my.exe
```

as well as written to registry i.e:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Automation\myapp
```

Now i have wix project developed to create msi using msbuild. I want the selected path in the GUI has to go into the source path in wix component. My wix code somewhat like below,

```
<Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
    <File Id='ExecutableFile' Name='my.exe' DiskId='1' Source='$(var.Sandbox)\my.exe' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>
</Component>
```

With above code, I get an error saying,

```
 error CNDL0150: Undefined pre processor variable '$(var.Sandbox)'
```

How can i pass the variable 'data' which is selected by the GUI to the file source path in wix?Is it possible to send the registry value to wix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the variable 'data' from the python script to wix as a msbuild property.Python script looks like below

```
data='C:\Sandbox\build\Windows\release\my.exe'
arg1 = '/t:Rebuild'
arg2 = '/p:Configuration=Release'
arg3 = '/p:Platform=x86'
arg4 = '/p:ExePath=data'
p = subprocess.call([self.msbuild,projpath,arg1,arg2,arg3])
```

and the make changes in your **wixproject** like below.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DefineConstants>
    Sandbox=$(ExePath)
    </DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and in your **wxs** file change the source path of your component as below

```
<Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='*'>
<File Id='ExecutableFile' Name='my.exe' DiskId='1' Source='$(var.Sandbox)\my.exe' KeyPath='yes' Checksum='yes'/>       
</Component>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `candle.exe` you need to pass the `data` variable through via a preprocessor variable named `Sandbox`. You do that with a snippet line that looks something like:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["candle.exe", "-dSandbox=" + data])
```

Of course, you'd need to add the path to your .wxs file and all that too.

Comment: Tried with your code.getting an error like below                         WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: My code is a snippet. You'll need to provide the rest of the code (including the files to compile and the output folder, if you're going to specify that) to make it work.